# ¿Como realizar un delete con in(select)?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
DELETE FROM abono where id='dos' in (select * FROM abono WHERE id='dos' limit 2,1)
```

pero mi mysql me dice

```
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

mi tabla se llama abono

```
id    | monto
'uno' | 5.00
'uno' | 3.79
'dos' | 4.00
'tres'| 1.00
'dos' | 2.90
'uno' | 6.00
'dos' | 7.50
'tres'| 9.00
```

como no tiene primary key utilizo esta consulta para decirle que indice eliminar

```
select * FROM abono WHERE id='dos' limit 2,1
```

me devuelve

```
id | monto
'dos | 7.50
```

pero no se como puedo eliminar ese dato

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta aqui `id='dos' in (`. Se supone que tienes que especificarle una columna para poder realizar el filtro como por ejemplo: `id ='dos' AND nombre_columna IN(....)`

Comment: me sale error si hago eso

Comment: Puedes dar mas detalles del error?

Comment: el mismo #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Enséñame el sql que utilizaste

Comment: DELETE FROM abono where id='dos' and monto in
(select monto FROM abono WHERE id='dos' limit 2,1)

Comment: ¿Por que tienes un limit en la subconsulta? ¿Realmente lo necesitas? ¿Que intentas hacer en la subconsulta? El error lo dice claro: tu versión de MySQL no soporta limit en una subconsulta (ni tampoco in, all, any o some)

Comment: Aparte del limit en la subconsulta, la consulta en sí no tiene sentido. Tienes una condición y luego un `in` sin nada. ¿Qué valor tiene que estar en el `in`?¿y por qué la subconsulta hace un select *? Sería bueno que explicaras la lógica detrás de tu código: ¿qué es lo que estás intentando hacer? ¿Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla con sin primary key y tengo repetidos los id y quiero eliminar una row x la identifico con esa consulta para eso necesito el limit

Comment: ¿Cómo determinas el `limit 2,1`? ¿Quieres eliminar siempre el último valor de ese `id`? ¿o viene de algún sitio en concreto?

Comment: limit n,1, n se lo paso dependiendo el usuario n=indice

Comment: Te puedo dar una solución, pero puede fallar si hay valores repetidos (mismo id y mismo monto) ya que borraría de más. Mi recomendación sería que le pongas un campo que haga de clave primaria (aunque sea una clave autoincrementada), porque trabajar con la tabla y los datos expuestos es insostenible.

Comment: Si, creo que es lo mejor gracias

Answer (score 2):

Como te ponía en los comentarios, el error especificado en el mensaje ocurre porque usas un `LIMIT` dentro de la subconsulta del `delete`. Hay que encontrar una manera que no use `LIMIT` en la subconsulta. Tampoco se puede usar la misma tabla del `delete` en la subconsulta que se utilice en las condiciones del `WHERE`.

Pero curiosamente, no se permite en la subconsulta directa pero sí en una subconsulta de una subconsulta (como puedes ver en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3f2/2)). Entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
DELETE FROM abono WHERE id = 'dos' AND monto = (SELECT monto FROM (SELECT monto FROM abono WHERE id='dos' LIMIT 2,1) AS m)
```

Aquí estilizado para que se lea mejor:

```
DELETE FROM abono 
WHERE  id = 'dos' 
  AND  monto = (
                SELECT monto FROM (
                                   SELECT monto FROM abono WHERE id='dos' LIMIT 2,1 
                                  ) AS m
               )
```

---

De todos modos, como te ponía en los comentarios, esta solución tiene un problema: si hay varios registros repetidos con id "dos" y monto 7.50, los va a borrar todos. Mi recomendación sería que buscaras otra opción, añadieses una clave primaria y optaras por algo más sencillo y sostenible.

.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general no se puede modificar los datos de una tabla usando subquery. Mira el siguiente enlace

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html

Una posición es renombrar la subquery

Comment: Lo que dice el enlace es que por lo general no se pueden modificar los datos de una tabla usando **esa misma tabla** en la subconsulta. La parte de la misma tabla es importante, porque se permiten subconsultas de otras tablas y de la misma tabla también (si se usa para una tabla derivada en el from).